# How to add alt text to background images? Making background images accessible

Tags: html, css, accessibility

I have a site that is displaying many of its images as background images using `background-size: cover` to size them to completely fill the element while cropping off any parts of the image that don't fit.

The problem is that these images are NOT purely decorative. They are a critical part of the informational content of the page. This means they need `alt` text in order to be accessible to screen readers and other assistive technologies.

What is the most semantic way to add `alt` descriptions to background images?

```css
article {
  position: relative;
  width: 320px;
  margin: 5rem auto;
}

figure {
  width: 100%;
  height: 180px;
  /* not accessible */
  background-image: url('http://www.fillmurray.com/300/300');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<article class="panel panel-default">
  <header class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">Title of Article</h4>
  </header>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <figure class="article-image"></figure>
  </div>
  <footer class="panel-footer">
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Read</a>
  </footer>
</article>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The most semantic way to make a background image accessible is to use both a background image and a regular `img` tag as well.

1. Place the `img` within the element with the background image.
2. Visually hide the `img` so that sighted users just see the background image behind it, but users with assistive technologies are still presented the `img`.

Note: just setting the image to `display: none;` will hide also it from assistive technologies, which isn't the goal. A different approach is needed.

If you're using Bootstrap, it has a handy built-in class for doing just this: `.sr-only`. If you're not, you can add the styles for that class to your own stylesheet:

```
.sr-only {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: 0;
}
```

Applying this technique to the example above looks like this:

```css
article {
  position: relative;
  width: 320px;
  margin: 5rem auto;
}

figure {
  width: 100%;
  height: 180px;
  /* not accessible */
  background-image: url('http://www.fillmurray.com/300/300');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<article class="panel panel-default">
  <header class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">Title of Article</h4>
  </header>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <figure class="article-image">
      <!-- include the img tag but visually hide it with .sr-only -->
      <img class="sr-only" alt="Bill Murray" src="http://www.fillmurray.com/300/300" />
    </figure>
  </div>
  <footer class="panel-footer">
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Read</a>
  </footer>
</article>
```

**Edit:** The [object-fit property](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/) eliminates the need for the background image, but at the time of writing this property is not fully supported in IE or Edge.

Comment: I guess that I don't understand the point here. Background images are inaccessible by design. The real issue here is that you're incorrectly using background images as regular images. Now that you've implemented a proper `img` element, why not just delete the background image property? I don't understand what value there is in keeping it in the CSS.

Comment: @Josh Using background image lets one leverage `background-size: [cover | contain]` for proportionally resizing any image to fill or fit within a container. This is the only way to achieve that affect in a non-brittle way without using javascript—which users may have disabled.

Comment: The only issue I have with this is that the image is removed from the document flow, thus the element that holds the image must be explicitly sized.

Comment: @p0lar_bear if you're displaying an image at its native ratio/size, you should just use an `img` tag by itself

Comment: Maybe currently the only answer to the question but I don't like the idea of additional downloads slowing down the page loading time. If using the same image referenced in src as in the background-image style, is there a way to ensure the image is only downloaded from the server once?

Comment: @authentictech browsers cache resources, so it will only download once

Comment: @Sean thanks. I suppose I could run some tests using the Inspector tool and make sure that is the case.

Answer (score 8):

The W3C provide an exemple for this context, simply provide a `role="img"` to the div and an `aria-label` with your description.

More informations here : http://mars.dequecloud.com/demo/ImgRole.htm

Comment: This solution doesn't work if the div has child elements that need to be interactive, like links.

Answer (score 2):

> This means they need alt text in order to be accessible to screen readers **and other assistive technologies**.

You perfectly right to point out that users may use assistive technologies which are not screen readers. Also, any method using `sr-only` CSS class must not be used as the sole way to ensure that the textual information may be accessed to every user.

For instance, people with low vision may want to discard all images which would appear blur and display their text alternative instead.

[The `object-fit` property works for images since Edge 16](https://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit) so it's no longer a problem for 92% of browsers, and [a fallback can be provided for older browsers.](https://github.com/bfred-it/object-fit-images/)